# How can I get locust to stop load testing based on response from another API?

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

We plan on doing load testing on a sequence of APIs using locust. So we have a set of APIs we would be calling sequentially on locust using SequentialTaskSet. By default it would run indefinitely if not stopped manually or I can set a timer in the command line to stop after a pre-defined interval. But what we plan to do is, we would be gradually increasing the number of concurrent users. Then we plan to call a separate API every 5 minutes or so which would give us memory consumed on the servers where our sequential APIs are hosted. If the value of memory consumed reaches a threshold, we want the locust script to stop automatically. I tried reading the documentation but couldn't find how we would go about doing this. Any tips?

Basic code we have so far:

````
import json

class UserBehavior(SequentialTaskSet):

    @task
    def api_call(self):

        with self.client.get('/test_api') as response:
            print(response)

class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [UserBehavior]
    wait_time = between(2, 10)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a User you can call

```
self.environment.runner.quit()
```

In distributed runs, that will only shut down that particular worker, so it isnt perfect.

If you dont want to run the check in a User, you can create your own greenlet that checks your metric in the background (the example checks a locust stats value, but you could just call your API there)

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html#run-a-background-greenlet

```
from locust import events
from locust.runners import STATE_STOPPING, STATE_STOPPED, STATE_CLEANUP, WorkerRunner

def checker(environment):
    while not environment.runner.state in [STATE_STOPPING, STATE_STOPPED, STATE_CLEANUP]:
        time.sleep(1)
        if environment.runner.stats.total.fail_ratio > 0.2:
            print(f"fail ratio was {environment.runner.stats.total.fail_ratio}, quitting")
            environment.runner.quit()
            return


@events.init.add_listener
def on_locust_init(environment, **_kwargs):
    # only run this on master & standalone
    if not isinstance(environment.runner, WorkerRunner):
        gevent.spawn(checker, environment)
```

Comment: Ok but my question was more in terms of how & where would we define the code that would run the API to get memory consumed every 5 minutes? I mean, if I put the method with task decorator it becomes part of the locust swarm which we don't want as we only want the API to run once every 5 minutes. If I define a method with no task decoration, then as per the documentation, wouldn't the locust framework just ignore it?

Comment: I see. I added to my answer.

Comment: Is there a way to stop tests only for some error codes? I don't want to stop tests on 404s but for 429s I do.

Comment: You can add an event handler for the request event that checks the response code for a specific request. https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html